# How do I find the local path to my uploaded file for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage. GCL specifies that I need to get the local path to my uploaded file. However, I can't seem to figure out how to find the local path to my uploaded file. Could someone please help me? I'm using Django, in case that's relevant. Thanks!

In the snippet below, you can see that GCL asks for a source_file_name that is supposed to be a local path to my uploaded file.

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The path to your file to upload
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )
```

Comment: Use Windows Explorer or **dir** command (Windows), the **find** or **ls** command (Linx), to find your file.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the file from different manner

- upload from filename, where you need to provide a file path to upload
- upload from file, where you provide only a file object (created as you which, it could be a in memory file for example)
- upload from string to directly write the string content in a file on GCS.

*more detail [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html)*

Use the manner the most suitable with your code context and your way to handle the files to upload.